# How to open a SwiftUI dropdown menu with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, menu, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI app where I have a dropdown menu implemented. The dropdown menu is opened by clicking on it. However, I need to add functionality so that the user can also open the dropdown menu by pressing a keyboard shortcut, in this case "Command + H".

Here is some part of the code:

```
Menu {
    ForEach(conversations, id: \.conversion_id) {
        conversation in
        Button(action: {
            selectedConversation = conversation.conversion_id
        })
        {
            Text(conversation.title)
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black) // Use color scheme for color
            .font(.system(size: 16))
        }
    }
}
label: {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
        Text(selectedConversation != "" ? conversations.first(where: {
            $0.conversion_id == selectedConversation
        })
             ?.title ?? "New Chat" : chatTitle.title)
        .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black) // Use color scheme for color
        .font(.system(size: 16))
        .frame(alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

I have tried using `keyboardShortcut` to achieve that.

```
Button(action: {
    selectedConversation = conversation.conversion_id
    }) {
        Text(conversation.title)
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
            .font(.system(size: 16))
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("n", modifiers: .command)
```

However, as appears it cannot be used for `Menu` for that purpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **complete View struct code that contains your menu** so we can see how you do it and work on a solution.

Comment: Command + h: SwiftUI won’t let you overwrite a standard shortcut. The menu won’t show it or respond to it.